# Why does the regex pattern g[a-z]+?d match 'godgood' as a single word in grep but works differently online?

Tags: regex

I'm learning regular expressions and encountered a behavior I can't explain. I have the text "godgood" and am using the regex pattern g[a-z]+?d. My goal is to match "god" and "good" as two separate words.

However, when I use this pattern in grep (version 3.7), it matches the entire "godgood" as a single word. On the other hand, when I try the same pattern on various online regex platforms, it correctly matches "god" and "good" separately.

Could someone explain why there is this discrepancy in behavior? Is there a difference in how grep version 3.7 handles this pattern compared to online regex engines? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

```
$ egrep -o 'g[a-z]+?d' file
godgood
```

Comment: `on various online regex platforms` Please be specific. Which platform with what setting with what input exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> why there is this discrepancy in behavior?

Because the "various online regex platforms" use different regex engine rules. In particular, `+?` is a non-greedy match in perl regex, whereas in extended regex `+?` is a greedy `+` followed by `?`.

`egrep` is deprecated. Use `grep -E`.

Comment: In fact, with `grep -P`, which uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, it matches twice.

Comment: I konw.Non-reedy matching exists in perl regular expressions